# OOD - Avoiding Duplicate Functions for Each Member Variable (Java)

Tags: java, mysql, oop

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44244018/avoid-duplicate-functions-for-each-member-variable) has a lot to do with what I am trying to accomplish and provides great insight. Although I feel the answer is still unclear since I'm using Java and not C++.

I have a class (SQLService) that has a SQL Connection and 3 tables that it manages using the JDBC library. I am building a private function (buildInsertQuery) that takes in each table with data and builds a dynamic insert statement based on the number of columns (See simple snippet below)

```
class SQLService {
    private Table table1;
    private Table table2;
    private Table table3;
    private Connection connection;

    private String buildInsertQuery() {
        // Builds SQL insert query String like "INSERT INTO blah (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?) 
    }
}
```

- One option is to create a separate function for each member variable. But, since the `buildInsertQuery()` function does the same thing no matter the table being used, I feel it would be very redundant to copy and paste the same code and name the function differently for each member variable.
- Another option is to pass the table in as a parameter to `buildInsertQuery` (i.e. `buildInsertQuery(Table table)`). But, after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810580/access-member-variables-directly-or-pass-as-parameter), I feel this is also very inefficient.

The article mentioned above had the solution of using Class member pointers. But, I wasn't sure if there was an equivalent in Java.

Thanks!

Comment: Building dynamic queries? Why, just why? SQL is not OOP. Use static queries!

Comment: Why does it have to manage three tables?  Why not devise a abstract implement which manages one table and build implementations around actual tables?

Comment: `java` is not `c++`   create a private base function with the generic functionality and table name as argument, add 3 methods specialized to the three tables which call the base function with corresponding table names.

Comment: @juergen for this specific case the number of tables is always fixed for an infinite time. But the number of columns from both the data I am reading in and the number of columns in each table will vary as time goes on. Thus, the statements cannot be static. I'm not asking SQL to be OOP, just trying to write solid code :)

Answer (score 0):

create a private base function with the generic functionality and table as argument, add 3 methods specialized to the three tables which call the base function with corresponding tables.

```
class SQLService {
    private Table table1;
    private Table table2;
    private Table table3;
    private Connection connection;

    private String buildInsertQuery(Table table) {
        // Builds SQL insert query String l
        ...
    }

    // perhaps memoize the result for reuse.
    String buildInsertQueryForTable1() {
        return buildInsertQuery(table1);
    }

    // similarly for other tables
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm initially doing. But isn't it still redundant that the member variables are being passed as arguments to buildInsertQuery() even though the function can access them directly? Definitely will have memoization implemented into this!

Comment: I don't know why and if it should bother me. I just feel that if I have member vars I need to use them as such.

Comment: If it makes you feel better convert the private method to static, with no access to instance variables.

Comment: Hmm I never thought about that idea! Even then I feel like that's not the true purpose of what a static method is made for since the method is dependent on the creation of the Tables in SQLService. What if I created a separate class called "SQLBuilder" or something like that and moved the logic over there?